# How to check if mod_alias is enabled?

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, rewrite, mod-alias

I want to try `mod_alias` instead of `mod_rewrite` for a couple of simple redirect rules, but the directives don't seem to be working when entered in `.htaccess`.  Is it possible that `mod_alias` is not loaded or enabled on the server?

How do I find out?

Answer (score 10):

You can check if mod_alias is enabled by using the following command:

```
~$ apache2ctl -M | grep alias
```

If it's enabled, it will give you the following response:

```
 alias_module (shared)
Syntax OK
```

You can also check manually the file which is loading the module:

```
~$ cat /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/alias.load
```

If it's enabled, it will give you the following response:

```
LoadModule alias_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_alias.so
```

Comment: -bash: apache2ctl: command not found

Comment: cat: /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/alias.load: No such file or directory

Comment: -bash: LoadModule: command not found

Comment: you can try httpd -M | grep alias

Comment: `httpd -M | grep alias
Syntax OK
 alias_module (static)`  - Does that mean it's on?

Answer (score 2):

You can try listing all active modules with one of these:

```
apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES
```

or

```
httpd -M
```

Also, check if the module is commented out in the httpd.conf file:

```
cat /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf | grep LoadModule
```

Comment: Hi, Gabriel.  I am getting '-bash: apachectl: command not found'.   Nevermind, the 'httpd -M' command worked

Comment: When running 'cat /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf | grep LoadModule'
I am getting 'LoadModule bwlimited_module modules/mod_bwlimited.so'